# Generate HTML5 based on files stored in a server

Tags: php, javascript, html, jsp, download

We are storing files on a server that will be downloaded through a browser by a customer.

We would like some way of generating the HTML5 based on the files in the server so that no one has to manually update the HTML every time a new file is uploaded.

The files will be stored in a tree style hierarchy so what I was thinking would be that maybe each folder would have its own HTML page with download links to sub folders and files.

Is this even possible and if so is it possible with JavaScript or am I looking in the wrong direction?

**EDIT :** After some looking around it seems I will need some type of server side language like PHP or JSP. As you can see I am very new to this type of programming and any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance and apologies if this is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a small [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) with a downloadgalery Plug-In or a simple filelist like this one: http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/4920/.